Max Value of a Binomial Random Variable
This questions relates to the following problem from a past actuary exam:
"A company establishes a fund of 120 from which it wants to pay an amount, C, to any of
its 20 employees who achieve a high performance level during the coming year. Each
employee has a 2% chance of achieving a high performance level during the coming
year. The events of different employees achieving a high performance level during the
coming year are mutually independent.
Calculate the maximum value of C for which the probability is less than 1% that the fund
will be inadequate to cover all payments for high performance."
The answer I obtained was $C=40$, but the correct answer is $C=60$ as explained here.  However, I'm still a bit stuck trying to figure out the flaw in my own reasoning, and am hoping someone might be able to help.  Here's how I arrived at $C=40$:
Let $K$ be the number of highly qualified employees.  Then $K$ has a binomial distribution, and the probability that $k$ employees are highly qualified is $p(K=k) = \binom{20}{k}(.02^{k})(.98^{n-k})$
For $1 \leq k \leq 20$, we want to find $C$ such if $120 - C*k \leq 0$ then $p(k = K) \leq .01$.
If $k=3$, then $C=40$ and $p(3) = .006$, but if $k=2$ then $C = 60$ and $p(k) = .05$. So $k$ must be 3 and $C=40$.
The correct solution involves finding $k$ such that $P(K\geq k) \leq .01$. How is setting $K\geq k$ equal to finding the max?  And why is this probability cumulative?  Thanks!

$K$ is a random variable, $k$ is a constant that you're looking for. So you want to find the largest $k$ such that $P(K \geq k) \leq .01$.  Your statement says we want to find C such that:  if payments are negative then p(k=K) <= .01. This is not what we want. We want that $P(120-Ck <0 ) \leq.01$.

"the probability is less than 1% that the fund will be inadequate to cover all payments for high performance." The fund will be inadequate iff $CK > 120$, i.e. $K> \frac {120}C$. This inequality is a hint to consider the cumulative probability: $p\left(K> \frac {120}C\right) < 1%$.

The event $K = k$ represents the outcome that exactly $k$ employees are high-performing in the coming year, so $\Pr[K = k]$ excludes the outcomes where there are less than $k$ high-performing employees.  Yet you want to ensure that the probability that the fund is inadequate does not exceed $0.01$; i.e., the probability that the fund is adequate is at least $0.99$.  The event that the fund is adequate comprises all outcomes for which the number of high-performing employees is less than or equal to some maximum number, which is why you must use a cumulative probability.
Let's put it another way.  Suppose you have a fair coin.  I offer you $10$ dollars for each head you flip out of $n = 10$ tosses, but I only have $60$ dollars in my pocket.  What is the set of outcomes for which I will not have enough money to pay you all your winnings?  Clearly, if the random number of heads you flip is $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 10, p = 0.5)$, then the event $X \ge 7$ (or equivalently, $X \in \{7, 8, 9, 10\}$ means I won't have enough money to pay you.  What is the probability of this event?  It is $$\Pr[X \ge 7] = \sum_{x=7}^{10} \binom{10}{x} (0.5)^x (1 - 0.5)^{10-x}.$$
You wouldn't tell me that only the event $X = 7$ is inadequate, because any greater number of heads will also be inadequate for me to cover.  In a similar way, the fund has set aside only $120$.  If they pay $C$ to every high-performing employee, then if $K > 120/C$, the fund will be inadequate.  For example, if $C = 10$, then all outcomes satisfying $K \ge 13$ will be inadequate for the company to fund.
So your method doesn't work because all you are doing is ensuring that the probability of each individual outcome, $\Pr[K = k]$, is below the $0.01$ threshold, but it is the sum of the probabilities of all such outcomes, that must be kept below this threshold.

"The event that the fund is adequate comprises all outcomes for which the number of high-performing employees is less than or equal to some maximum number, which is why you must use a cumulative probability."  That clarified it for me.  Thanks very much for taking the time to write such a thoughtful answer.  Much appreciated!

$\mathbb{P}(K=0)=.67$
$\mathbb{P}(K=1)=.27$
This tells me that
$\mathbb{P}(K\geq2)>1\%$ and that $\mathbb{P}(K\geq3)<1\%$.
This means that C must be such that funds are not sufficient for $K\geq3$.
C=40 will have enough for K=3, so must be C=60.
The probability must be less than 1% that there is not enough. That happens if too many people qualify. If 3 people are too many, than 4, 5, 6, … will also be too many. So it is not just $P(K=3)$ that needs to be smaller than 1% it is $P(K\geq3)$ that needs to be smaller than 1%.

Thank you for your comment!
